# Get JavaScript Array in ASP.Net ArrayList as a parameter of a function

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, arraylist

I am working on a project and have to send a JavaScript Array as a parameter of a ASP.Net function which parameter is ArrayList.

Below is my code,

JavaScript :

```
        var propertyArray = new Array();
        propertyArray.push("2");
        propertyArray.push("3");

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'Default.aspx/SaveTextProperty',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: { propertyArray: propertyArray },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (response) {
                var result = "Done";
                alert(result);
            }
        });
```

Default.aspx :

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static bool SaveTextProperty(ArrayList propertyArray)
    {
          //Some code
          return true;
    }
```

Here I need to get JavaScript propertyArray as ASP.Net function named SaveTextProperty's parameter.
How can I get it?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use as follow

```
[WebMethod]
public static bool SaveTextProperty(List<string> arr)
{
      //Some code
      return true;
}
```

and jquery

```
var propertyArray = new Array();
    propertyArray.push("2");
    propertyArray.push("3");

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'Default.aspx/SaveTextProperty',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify({ arr: propertyArray }),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: onSuccess,
        failure: onError
    });

function onSuccess(response) {
    alert(response.d);
}

function onError() {
    alert("fail");
}
```